# Reactivating a Googleads account

Tags: google-adsense

The owner of a website says that they clicked a few times on their old Googleads account and probably caused it to be deactivated. I created a new one from scratch and asked him to avoid any clicking. The new account has been disabled and I'd like to find ways to reactivate it as well as prevent any future deactivation. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think creating a second account after the first was deactivated for click fraud only hurt their chances of ever getting an Adsense again. You probably should look into alternative ad sources.

Comment: @John Conde: I understand. It's not as clear cut as it sounds. The idea was to put some adverts back on and I have no idea why they were deactivated the first time (the last webmaster left no notes or anything). The owner only admitted he'd clicked on the adverts after I'd opened the new account.

Comment: I contacted with Google with two disabled accounts (40 euro in one of these accounts) but they did not accept my reasons.I hate google adsense since that non-deserved disable.

Comment: Sorry to hear that HerkesUzman. Having an account disabled isn't such an issue but not being able to use to service without knowing why is kind of harsh.

Answer (score 1):

Try contacting adsense and explaining the situation to them. You might be able to get them to reactivate your account.